# Extracting a variable from a list

Tags: r

i am working in the time series data, i am using the **vector auto regressive model ** for the forecasting purpose.I obtain the result in form of a list as:

```
head(pred.ff1)
[[1]]
[[1]]$`X1`
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.09487087 -0.3414799 0.1517382 0.2466091

[[1]]$X2
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X2.fcst 0.009847315 -0.1743455 0.1940402 0.1841929

[[1]]$X3
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X3.fcst -0.04753275 -0.1567682 0.06170268 0.1092354

[[1]]$X4
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst -0.03430398 -0.1694137 0.1008057 0.1351097

[[1]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.03795605 -0.1407119 0.06479983 0.1027559

[[1]]$X6
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X6.fcst 0.002768355 -0.07327401 0.07881072 0.07604236

[[1]]$X7
              fcst       lower      upper        CI
X7.fcst 0.03232304 -0.02948146 0.09412754 0.0618045

[[1]]$X8
               fcst     lower      upper       CI
X8.fcst 0.002286995 -0.041158 0.04573199 0.043445

[[1]]$X9
              fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.00562756 -0.03687652 0.04813164 0.04250408

[[1]]$X10
                 fcst      lower     upper         CI
X10.fcst 0.0002040489 -0.0233304 0.0237385 0.02353445

[[1]]$X11
                 fcst      lower      upper         CI
X11.fcst -0.001280991 -0.0232918 0.02072981 0.02201081

[[1]]$X12
                 fcst       lower      upper         CI
X12.fcst -0.001215482 -0.01226777 0.00983681 0.01105229

[[1]]$X13
                  fcst       lower       upper          CI
X13.fcst -4.677221e-05 -0.00615902 0.006065476 0.006112248

[[1]]$X14
                 fcst        lower     upper          CI
X14.fcst 0.0005448491 -0.002823002 0.0039127 0.003367851

[[1]]$X15
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst -0.0001634004 -0.003161533 0.002834732 0.002998132

[[1]]$X16
                  fcst        lower      upper          CI
X16.fcst -2.153563e-05 -0.001758731 0.00171566 0.001737196

[[1]]$X17
                  fcst       lower       upper          CI
X17.fcst -0.0001725442 -0.00180384 0.001458751 0.001631295

[[1]]$X18
                 fcst        lower        upper           CI
X18.fcst 0.0001222982 -0.000507831 0.0007524273 0.0006301292

[[1]]$X19
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X19.fcst -1.407699e-05 -0.0004560961 0.0004279422 0.0004420192

[[1]]$X20
                  fcst         lower       upper           CI
X20.fcst -1.410341e-05 -0.0002851748 0.000256968 0.0002710714

[[1]]$X21
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X21.fcst -2.852586e-05 -0.0003024134 0.0002453617 0.0002738876

[[1]]$X22
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst -5.94118e-06 -0.0001843939 0.0001725115 0.0001784527

[[1]]$X23
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X23.fcst 8.176983e-06 -0.0001655926 0.0001819466 0.0001737696


[[2]]
[[2]]$`X1`
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.08733008 -0.3367695 0.1621094 0.2494394

[[2]]$X2
                fcst      lower     upper        CI
X2.fcst -0.009411053 -0.1958589 0.1770367 0.1864478

[[2]]$X3
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X3.fcst -0.05347263 -0.1653522 0.05840698 0.1118796

[[2]]$X4
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst -0.01666991 -0.1528375 0.1194976 0.1361675

[[2]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.05900454 -0.1656444 0.04763533 0.1066399

[[2]]$X6
              fcst       lower      upper        CI
X6.fcst 0.02015866 -0.05162044 0.09193776 0.0717791

[[2]]$X7
              fcst       lower      upper         CI
X7.fcst 0.01691519 -0.05284199 0.08667237 0.06975718

[[2]]$X8
                 fcst       lower      upper         CI
X8.fcst -6.677678e-05 -0.04564592 0.04551237 0.04557914

[[2]]$X9
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.008862045 -0.03400812 0.05173221 0.04287017

[[2]]$X10
                  fcst      lower      upper         CI
X10.fcst -0.0008544369 -0.0244056 0.02269673 0.02355116

[[2]]$X11
                 fcst       lower      upper         CI
X11.fcst 0.0005725848 -0.02231949 0.02346466 0.02289207

[[2]]$X12
                  fcst    lower      upper        CI
X12.fcst -0.0005001068 -0.01126 0.01025979 0.0107599

[[2]]$X13
                 fcst        lower      upper         CI
X13.fcst 0.0007129809 -0.009680679 0.01110664 0.01039366

[[2]]$X14
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X14.fcst -0.0001235468 -0.004706546 0.004459452 0.004582999

[[2]]$X15
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst -0.0003864978 -0.004725561 0.003952565 0.004339063

[[2]]$X16
                  fcst        lower       upper         CI
X16.fcst -0.0001176655 -0.002174595 0.001939264 0.00205693

[[2]]$X17
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X17.fcst -8.402007e-05 -0.002140599 0.001972559 0.002056579

[[2]]$X18
                 fcst         lower       upper          CI
X18.fcst 3.578998e-05 -0.0009875194 0.001059099 0.001023309

[[2]]$X19
                 fcst        lower       upper           CI
X19.fcst 3.648989e-05 -0.000950025 0.001023005 0.0009865149

[[2]]$X20
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X20.fcst -5.581126e-05 -0.0006018023 0.0004901798 0.0005459911

[[2]]$X21
                  fcst         lower        upper          CI
X21.fcst -3.404841e-05 -0.0005578064 0.0004897096 0.000523758

[[2]]$X22
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst 6.007921e-06 -0.0003487766 0.0003607924 0.0003547845

[[2]]$X23
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X23.fcst -2.992276e-05 -0.0003617254 0.0003018799 0.0003318027


[[3]]
[[3]]$`X1`
              fcst      lower     upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.1368855 -0.3795483 0.1057773 0.2426628

[[3]]$X2
                fcst     lower     upper        CI
X2.fcst -0.005708551 -0.187317 0.1758999 0.1816085

[[3]]$X3
               fcst      lower      upper       CI
X3.fcst -0.02137126 -0.1251562 0.08241372 0.103785

[[3]]$X4
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst -0.02786166 -0.1643109 0.1085876 0.1364492

[[3]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.04794332 -0.1543581 0.05847146 0.1064148

[[3]]$X6
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X6.fcst 0.001945018 -0.07375121 0.07764125 0.07569623

[[3]]$X7
               fcst      lower      upper         CI
X7.fcst 0.006862673 -0.0585679 0.07229325 0.06543057

[[3]]$X8
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X8.fcst 0.006563406 -0.04470572 0.05783253 0.05126912

[[3]]$X9
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.004387015 -0.02809655 0.03687058 0.03248357

[[3]]$X10
                fcst       lower      upper         CI
X10.fcst 0.003081756 -0.01933266 0.02549617 0.02241442

[[3]]$X11
                fcst     lower      upper         CI
X11.fcst 0.003600291 -0.016025 0.02322558 0.01962529

[[3]]$X12
                 fcst       lower       upper         CI
X12.fcst -0.001727104 -0.01207136 0.008617155 0.01034426

[[3]]$X13
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X13.fcst -0.000390423 -0.006572372 0.005791526 0.006181949

[[3]]$X14
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X14.fcst 1.149518e-05 -0.003354279 0.003377269 0.003365774

[[3]]$X15
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst 0.0001177057 -0.002739912 0.002975324 0.002857618

[[3]]$X16
                 fcst        lower       upper         CI
X16.fcst 0.0001095768 -0.001255713 0.001474867 0.00136529

[[3]]$X17
                 fcst         lower       upper          CI
X17.fcst 9.308572e-05 -0.0009288719 0.001115043 0.001021958

[[3]]$X18
                 fcst         lower        upper          CI
X18.fcst 3.496647e-05 -0.0005539365 0.0006238694 0.000588903

[[3]]$X19
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X19.fcst 1.093539e-05 -0.0005480608 0.0005699316 0.0005589962

[[3]]$X20
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X20.fcst -5.208121e-05 -0.0003491431 0.0002449807 0.0002970619

[[3]]$X21
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X21.fcst 4.417278e-05 -0.0001926168 0.0002809624 0.0002367896

[[3]]$X22
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst -1.106024e-05 -0.0001799231 0.0001578026 0.0001688629

[[3]]$X23
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X23.fcst 1.133811e-06 -0.0001438627 0.0001461303 0.0001449965


[[4]]
[[4]]$`X1`
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.08233607 -0.3347495 0.1700773 0.2524134

[[4]]$X2
              fcst      lower     upper       CI
X2.fcst 0.01641975 -0.1682033 0.2010428 0.184623

[[4]]$X3
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X3.fcst -0.05674602 -0.1658435 0.05235143 0.1090975

[[4]]$X4
             fcst      lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst 0.0010726 -0.1377236 0.1398688 0.1387962

[[4]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.06739492 -0.1709187 0.03612888 0.1035238

[[4]]$X6
              fcst       lower      upper         CI
X6.fcst 0.02522976 -0.04636526 0.09682477 0.07159502

[[4]]$X7
              fcst      lower      upper         CI
X7.fcst 0.00766237 -0.0629829 0.07830764 0.07064527

[[4]]$X8
                fcst     lower      upper         CI
X8.fcst 0.0004687828 -0.044669 0.04560657 0.04513778

[[4]]$X9
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.009038821 -0.03367422 0.05175186 0.04271304

[[4]]$X10
                 fcst       lower      upper         CI
X10.fcst 0.0004137327 -0.02421099 0.02503845 0.02462472

[[4]]$X11
                  fcst       lower      upper        CI
X11.fcst -0.0002610677 -0.02264436 0.02212223 0.0223833

[[4]]$X12
                  fcst       lower      upper         CI
X12.fcst -0.0004309636 -0.01141709 0.01055516 0.01098613

[[4]]$X13
                  fcst       lower      upper        CI
X13.fcst -2.565239e-05 -0.01065386 0.01060255 0.0106282

[[4]]$X14
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X14.fcst 0.0002904256 -0.004379269 0.004960121 0.004669695

[[4]]$X15
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst 0.0003256191 -0.004119316 0.004770554 0.004444935

[[4]]$X16
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X16.fcst -2.55062e-05 -0.002174334 0.002123322 0.002148828

[[4]]$X17
                 fcst        lower      upper          CI
X17.fcst 8.012375e-05 -0.001931162 0.00209141 0.002011286

[[4]]$X18
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X18.fcst -2.323776e-05 -0.001062624 0.001016149 0.001039387

[[4]]$X19
                 fcst         lower       upper         CI
X19.fcst 6.843817e-05 -0.0009600714 0.001096948 0.00102851

[[4]]$X20
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X20.fcst 3.604862e-05 -0.0005144648 0.0005865621 0.0005505134

[[4]]$X21
                  fcst        lower        upper           CI
X21.fcst -2.143147e-05 -0.000553726 0.0005108631 0.0005322946

[[4]]$X22
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst 2.160088e-05 -0.0003303335 0.0003735352 0.0003519344

[[4]]$X23
                 fcst         lower        upper          CI
X23.fcst 3.327767e-05 -0.0003118393 0.0003783947 0.000345117


[[5]]
[[5]]$`X1`
               fcst      lower    upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.04868685 -0.2924447 0.195071 0.2437579

[[5]]$X2
              fcst      lower     upper        CI
X2.fcst 0.01944127 -0.1558611 0.1947436 0.1753023

[[5]]$X3
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X3.fcst -0.05912349 -0.1787382 0.06049122 0.1196147

[[5]]$X4
               fcst     lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst 0.000790435 -0.133067 0.1346478 0.1338574

[[5]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.04436822 -0.1480899 0.05935342 0.1037216

[[5]]$X6
              fcst      lower      upper         CI
X6.fcst 0.01999174 -0.0536216 0.09360508 0.07361334

[[5]]$X7
              fcst       lower      upper        CI
X7.fcst 0.02437102 -0.03822048 0.08696252 0.0625915

[[5]]$X8
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X8.fcst 0.005048194 -0.04023903 0.05033542 0.04528723

[[5]]$X9
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.003520865 -0.03572938 0.04277111 0.03925024

[[5]]$X10
                 fcst       lower      upper         CI
X10.fcst 0.0004501291 -0.02144116 0.02234141 0.02189128

[[5]]$X11
                fcst       lower      upper         CI
X11.fcst -0.00198129 -0.01868303 0.01472045 0.01670174

[[5]]$X12
                 fcst       lower       upper          CI
X12.fcst -0.003224955 -0.01193771 0.005487801 0.008712756

[[5]]$X13
                 fcst        lower       upper          CI
X13.fcst 6.650063e-05 -0.006047262 0.006180264 0.006113763

[[5]]$X14
                 fcst        lower      upper          CI
X14.fcst 0.0003066257 -0.003016529 0.00362978 0.003323155

[[5]]$X15
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst -0.0001549307 -0.002493142 0.002183281 0.002338212

[[5]]$X16
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X16.fcst -9.185101e-05 -0.001325417 0.001141715 0.001233566

[[5]]$X17
                 fcst         lower       upper          CI
X17.fcst 0.0001622149 -0.0009489518 0.001273382 0.001111167

[[5]]$X18
                 fcst        lower        upper           CI
X18.fcst 8.424326e-06 -0.000522949 0.0005397977 0.0005313734

[[5]]$X19
               fcst         lower        upper           CI
X19.fcst 7.8067e-05 -0.0003651451 0.0005212791 0.0004432121

[[5]]$X20
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X20.fcst -2.959462e-06 -0.0002856894 0.0002797705 0.0002827299

[[5]]$X21
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X21.fcst 6.624124e-06 -0.0002114546 0.0002247029 0.0002180787

[[5]]$X22
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst -1.741816e-05 -0.0001709704 0.0001361341 0.0001535523

[[5]]$X23
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X23.fcst -2.847981e-06 -0.000140082 0.000134386 0.000137234


[[6]]
[[6]]$`X1`
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X1.fcst -0.01496334 -0.2581869 0.2282603 0.2432236

[[6]]$X2
                 fcst      lower     upper        CI
X2.fcst -0.0008188325 -0.1817786 0.1801409 0.1809597

[[6]]$X3
               fcst      lower     upper        CI
X3.fcst -0.06367314 -0.1719374 0.0445911 0.1082642

[[6]]$X4
                fcst      lower     upper        CI
X4.fcst -0.004199702 -0.1381505 0.1297511 0.1339508

[[6]]$X5
               fcst      lower      upper        CI
X5.fcst -0.03906894 -0.1419927 0.06385484 0.1029238

[[6]]$X6
              fcst       lower      upper         CI
X6.fcst 0.01197404 -0.06155047 0.08549855 0.07352451

[[6]]$X7
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X7.fcst 0.004993964 -0.06041761 0.07040554 0.06541158

[[6]]$X8
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X8.fcst 0.000895556 -0.05228708 0.05407819 0.05318264

[[6]]$X9
               fcst       lower      upper         CI
X9.fcst 0.006909205 -0.02424421 0.03806262 0.03115341

[[6]]$X10
                  fcst       lower      upper        CI
X10.fcst -0.0001954779 -0.02108358 0.02069262 0.0208881

[[6]]$X11
                fcst       lower     upper         CI
X11.fcst 0.005666716 -0.01526266 0.0265961 0.02092938

[[6]]$X12
                  fcst       lower       upper         CI
X12.fcst -0.0007495571 -0.01129111 0.009791993 0.01054155

[[6]]$X13
                 fcst       lower      upper          CI
X13.fcst 0.0003540454 -0.00932208 0.01003017 0.009676126

[[6]]$X14
                  fcst        lower       upper         CI
X14.fcst -7.208348e-06 -0.004764258 0.004749841 0.00475705

[[6]]$X15
                  fcst        lower       upper          CI
X15.fcst -0.0001935391 -0.004438785 0.004051707 0.004245246

[[6]]$X16
                 fcst        lower       upper         CI
X16.fcst 2.498701e-05 -0.001796133 0.001846107 0.00182112

[[6]]$X17
                  fcst        lower        upper          CI
X17.fcst -0.0001306077 -0.001214511 0.0009532957 0.001083903

[[6]]$X18
                  fcst        lower        upper           CI
X18.fcst -8.081055e-06 -0.000712271 0.0006961089 0.0007041899

[[6]]$X19
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X19.fcst 0.0001211447 -0.0004897708 0.0007320603 0.0006109156

[[6]]$X20
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X20.fcst 6.514196e-06 -0.0003684692 0.0003814976 0.0003749834

[[6]]$X21
                  fcst         lower        upper           CI
X21.fcst -1.604373e-05 -0.0003358498 0.0003037623 0.0003198061

[[6]]$X22
                 fcst         lower        upper           CI
X22.fcst 2.121841e-06 -0.0002342708 0.0002385145 0.0002363926

[[6]]$X23
                  fcst        lower        upper           CI
X23.fcst -1.976261e-05 -0.000232734 0.0001932088 0.0002129714
```

now i want to extract the variable **fcst** only for my further analysis. I use the code:

```
ad1 <- lapply(pred.ff1[[1]], "[", 1)
```

but this code extract the first twenty three values of **fcst**. but i need all the 8395 values of ** fcst**. Can any body help me in solving my problem i will be thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a nested list,  try to `unlist` one level and then extract by position

```
sapply(unlist(pred.ff1, recursive = FALSE), `[`, 1)
```

Or by name

```
sapply(unlist(pred.ff1, recursive = FALSE), `[`, 'fcst')
```

Comment: thanks alot Ronak shah for your valuable suggestion its really works know i want to extract the first 8395 values from this, plz help how i extract these values

Comment: Try : `head(sapply(unlist(pred.ff1, recursive = FALSE), \`[\`, 1), 8395)`